# Retrieve and create ShellItemArray for IDesktopWallpaper::GetSlideshow method

Tags: c#

I did a large research on this but I did not find I am looking for.

I am going to use the IDesktopWallpaper::GetSlideshow method to retrieve the ShellItemArray and wanne set this by IDesktopWallpaper::SetSlideshow
[MS Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-setslideshow)

Unfortunately I cannot find a solution.
I learned to use Native methods and also found native COM interfaces for IShellItem and IShellItemArray and load them to my project.
Now I am struggeling, how to use them and how to retrieve and set the array from and to the Wallpaper Slideshow. I also found out I need the Marshal method for retrieving from memory. I am lost.

I would like to read the current ShellItems in this ShellItemArray from slideshow and wanne set them by a wrapper class.
**Any help is much appreciated!**

This is my current code doing the magic.

```
        public void GetSlideShow()
        {
            IntPtr slideshow = iDesktopWallpaper.GetSlideshow();
            NativeMethods.IShellItemArray shellArray;
            var x = (NativeMethods.IShellItemArray)Marshal.PtrToStructure(slideshow, typeof(NativeMethods.IShellItemArray));

        }
```

`This is the COM class for IDesktopWallpaper:`

```
// based off of https://bitbucket.org/ciniml/desktopwallpaper
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/// <summary>
///             IDesktopWallpaper Wallpaper = (IDesktopWallpaper)new DesktopWallpaper();
///             List<string> monitors = new List<string>();
///             uint monitorCount = Wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathCount();
///             for (uint i = 0; i < monitorCount; i++)
///             {
///                 monitors.Add(Wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathAt(i));
///             }
///             foreach (var item in monitors)
///             {
///                 Wallpaper.SetWallpaper(item, filename);
///             }
/// </summary>

[ComImport]
[Guid("B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDesktopWallpaper
{
    void SetWallpaper([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string wallpaper);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string GetWallpaper([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string GetMonitorDevicePathAt(uint monitorIndex);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint GetMonitorDevicePathCount();

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    Rect GetMonitorRECT([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID);

    void SetBackgroundColor([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint color);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint GetBackgroundColor();

    void SetPosition([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] IDesktopWallpaperPosition position);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    IDesktopWallpaperPosition GetPosition();

    void SetSlideshow(IntPtr items);

    IntPtr GetSlideshow();

    void SetSlideshowOptions(DesktopSlideshowDirection options, uint slideshowTick);

    void GetSlideshowOptions(out DesktopSlideshowDirection options, out uint slideshowTick);

    void AdvanceSlideshow([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] DesktopSlideshowDirection direction);

    DesktopSlideshowDirection GetStatus();

    bool Enable();
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD")]
public class DesktopWallpaper
{
}

[Flags]
public enum DesktopSlideshowOptions
{
    None = 0,
    ShuffleImages = 0x01
}

[Flags]
public enum DesktopSlideshowState
{
    None = 0,
    Enabled = 0x01,
    Slideshow = 0x02,
    DisabledByRemoteSession = 0x04
}

public enum DesktopSlideshowDirection
{
    Forward = 0,
    Backward = 1
}

public enum IDesktopWallpaperPosition
{
    Center = 0,
    Tile = 1,
    Stretch = 2,
    Fit = 3,
    Fill = 4,
    Span = 5,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

This is my Shell COM interface

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/// <summary>
/// https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions
/// </summary>
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    #region Constants

    public const uint S_OK = 0x0000;

    #endregion

    #region COM

    [ComImport, Guid("43826D1E-E718-42EE-BC55-A1E261C37BFE"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IShellItem
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint BindToHandler([In] IntPtr pbc, [In] ref Guid rbhid, [In] ref Guid riid, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IntPtr ppvOut);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetParent([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetDisplayName([In] uint sigdnName, out IntPtr ppszName);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetAttributes([In] uint sfgaoMask, out uint psfgaoAttribs);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint Compare([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IShellItem psi, [In] uint hint, out int piOrder);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("b63ea76d-1f85-456f-a19c-48159efa858b"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IShellItemArray
    {
        // Not supported: IBindCtx
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint BindToHandler([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pbc, [In] ref Guid rbhid, [In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvOut);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetPropertyStore([In] int Flags, [In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetPropertyDescriptionList([In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppv);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetAttributes([In] uint sfgaoMask, out uint psfgaoAttribs);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetCount(out uint pdwNumItems);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint GetItemAt([In] uint dwIndex, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi);

        // Not supported: IEnumShellItems (will use GetCount and GetItemAt instead)
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        uint EnumItems([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IntPtr ppenumShellItems);
    }

    #endregion

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int SHCreateItemFromParsingName(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPath,
        IntPtr pbc,
        ref Guid riid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppv);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
    internal static extern void SHCreateShellItemArrayFromShellItem(
     [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface, IidParameterIndex = 2)] IShellItem psi,
     [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid iIdIShellItem,
     [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface, IidParameterIndex = 2)] out IShellItemArray iShellItemArray);

    public static IShellItemArray GetShellItemArray(IShellItem shellItem)
    {
        IShellItemArray iShellItemArray = null;
        Guid iIdIShellItemArray = new Guid("b63ea76d-1f85-456f-a19c-48159efa858b");
        SHCreateShellItemArrayFromShellItem(shellItem, iIdIShellItemArray, out iShellItemArray);

        return iShellItemArray;
    }
    public class ShellArray : IShellItemArray
    {
        public uint BindToHandler([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pbc, [In] ref Guid rbhid, [In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvOut)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public uint GetPropertyStore([In] int Flags, [In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppv)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public uint GetPropertyDescriptionList([In] ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppv)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public uint GetAttributes([In] uint sfgaoMask, out uint psfgaoAttribs)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public uint GetCount(out uint pdwNumItems)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public uint GetItemAt([In] uint dwIndex, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItem ppsi)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public uint EnumItems([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IntPtr ppenumShellItems)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct PROPERTYKEY
        {
            internal Guid fmtid;
            internal uint pid;
        }

    }
}
```

I get the Exception

`System.MissingMethodException: "Es kann keine Schnittstelleninstanz erstellt werden."`

on line

`var x = (NativeMethods.IShellItemArray)Marshal.PtrToStructure(slideshow, typeof(NativeMethods.IShellItemArray));`

Comment: Why are you defining `IntPtr GetSlideshow();` instead of the obvious `IShellItemArray GetSlideshow();`? After that, you don't need to do anything else, because you have `IShellItemArray slideshow = iDesktopWallpaper.GetSlideshow();`, then you can query the current state, e.g., `slideshow.GetItemAt(0, out IShellItem item);`. Now `item` is a `ShellItem`  object, you can, e.g., get the path of the slideshow folder as `uint hresult = item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, out string name);`

Comment: NOTE: Defining the `IDesktopWallpaper` Interface, it's better to also specify its CoClass, which is the `DesktopWallpaper` class you already have there. So add `CoClass(typeof(DesktopWallpaper))` to the Attributes of `IDesktopWallpaper`. Then create the interface through the CoClass, e.g., `var desktopWallpaper = (IDesktopWallpaper)new DesktopWallpaper();`

Comment: Wow, that was very helpful.
I have had some errors in the methods of my "stolen" interfaces of IShellItem and IShellItemArray and of cause in the interface of IDesktopWallpaper.
The methods for retrieving the SlideShow and setting the Slideshow is not working.
If the working code is useful, then let me know.
THX AGAIN!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand what is not working. As a note, I wouldn't declare a number of functions the same way. E.g., in `IShellItem`, I'd have `uint GetDisplayName([In] uint sigdnName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszName);`. So you can read the string values directly. But, also, instead of `uint sigdnName` I would use an enumerator that defines the available values, etc.

Comment: To call `SetWallpaper()`, you first need the Monitor ID, since each monitor can have its own wallpaper / slideshow. If you pass a Folder, use `SHCreateItemFromParsingName`, if you need to create an array of paths (multiple images), use `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists`

Comment: Thanks Jimi.
I fixed the IDesktopWallpaper here.

`        uint GetSlideshow(out IShellItemArray shellItemArray);`

Then I can call
`                    IShellItemArray slideshow;
                    desktopWallpaper.GetSlideshow(out slideshow);
`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed the IDesktopWallpaper at line

```
uint GetSlideshow(out IShellItemArray shellItemArray);
```

Then I call

```
IShellItemArray slideshow;
desktopWallpaper.GetSlideshow(out slideshow);
```

Comment: You can write `desktopWallpaper.GetSlideshow(out IShellItemArray slideshow);`. Test `slideshow` for `null` before using it, then check the `Count` value. If it's `1`, you probably get the path of the Folder that contains the images